# Showing $f$ is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is from a Real Analysis practice midterm I found online (since mine is tomorrow, I was looking for practice questions):

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a measurable function. Suppose that there exists $M>0$ such that $\int_0^{1-\frac{1}{n}}f(x)d\mu \leq M$ for all $n \geq 1$. Show that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$

The goal is to show that $\int_{0}^1 f d\mu < \infty$.

Define $E_n = [0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ and $E = [0,1] = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$

Define $f_n(x) = f(x)\chi_{E_n}$. Then $\int_0^{1-\frac{1}{n}}f(x)d\mu = \int_{E_n}f_n(x)d\mu$.

$f_n$ is an increasing sequence of functions, converges to $f$, and $f_n \leq g = M$ for all $n$. So by DCT:

$\int_0^1 f d\mu = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{E_n}f_n d\mu \leq M $

I feel like this argument is fully sound so is there a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Better, "$f_n$ is an increasing *sequence* of functions".

Comment: @BrianO Whoops... my bad

Comment: (I added an 's', functions plural. No biggie.)

Comment: After "$f_n$ is an increasing sequence of functions", I firmly expected that you use the _monotone_ convergence theorem.

Comment: The solution is incorrect, because it is not necessarily true that $f_n \leq M$ for all $n$. Therefore, you need to use MCT, not DCT.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is it therefore right to say that since $f_n$ converges to $f$ and $f_n$ is monotonically increasing, I get the result from MCT?

Comment: @Shalop I thought since $f_n \leq f$, we have $\int_0^{1-\frac{1}{n}} f(x) d\mu \leq \int_0^{1-\frac{1}{n}} f_n(x) d\mu \leq M$?

Comment: The integrals are dominated by $M$. That doesn't imply that the functions themselves are dominated by $M$.

Comment: "and $f_n$ is monotonically increasing" is ambiguous, it could be read as "each function $f_n$ is monotonically increasing", which need not be the case. Better say "and $(f_n)$ is a monotonically increasing sequence". And that gets you the result with the MCT.

Comment: @Shalop Ah ok I see why I need to use MCT over DCT now. Thank you

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah yes, forgot the brackets to indicate I meant the sequence of functions. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

No, your argument is invalid. Indeed, the constant function $g(x) = M$ might not be a majorant.

As pointed out by Daniel Fischer, try the monotone convergence theorem.